# File content missing when i download from s3

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am using node.js aws sdk for s3 related methods. I have a method to download the file from s3 bucket.

I am downloading the file using the below code.

```
const downloadFileBase64 = async (payload) => {
  let params = { Bucket: s3BucketName, Key: `${payload.folderName}/${payload.fileName}` };
  try {
    const response = await s3
      .getObject(params, (err) => {
        if (err) {
          return err;
        }
      })
      .promise();

    return {
      data: response.Body.toString('base64'),
      fileName: payload.fileName
    };
  } catch (error) {
    return Boom.badRequest(error.message);
  }
};
```

Once i get the base64 content i am sending it over an email using sendgrid.

**Issue:** When i download small files everything is working fine. But when i download large files, some part of the file is missing in multiple pages. I just copy pasted the base64 in few online websites and downloaded the file from there, it's the same issue in those websites also. With this i concluded that there is some issue while returning the response from s3 itself. When i go to s3 and check it in the folder, it's showing proper file.

[image]

If you see the above screenshot, its the pdf which is having some random grey background in few pages and some text is also missing from the pdf.

I tried to use another method which just download buffer excluding the base64 conversion as shown below.

```
const downloadFileBuffer = async (payload) => {
  let params = { Bucket: s3BucketName, Key: `${payload.folderName}/${payload.fileName}` };
  try {
    const response = await s3
      .getObject(params, (err) => {
        if (err) {
          return err;
        }
      })
      .promise();

    return {
      data: response.Body,
      fileName: payload.fileName
    };
  } catch (error) {
    return Boom.badRequest(error.message);
  }
};
```

And once i get the file content in this above response, i am storing temporarily in a folder on server and then reading again and sending over email. But i am still having the same issue.

```
const fileContent = await docs.downloadFileBuffer({ payload: req.payload.action.dire });
await fs.writeFileSync(`${temp}testinggg.pdf`, fileContent?.data);
const fileData = await fs.readFileSync(`${temp}testinggg.pdf`, { encoding: 'base64' });
```

Any help on this issue is really appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After days of research and trying different ways, I found the issue. The issue was with `.promise()` used in `s3.getObject(params, (err) => {}).promise();`. Instead of that, I used callback using `Promise` as shown below. Now the file is properly showing the full content without missing any data.

```
const downloadFileBuffer = async (payload) => {
  let params = { Bucket: s3BucketName, Key: `${payload.folderName}/${payload.fileName}` };
  try {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      s3.getObject(params, (err, response) => {
        if (err) {
          reject(err);
        }
        resolve({
          data: response.Body,
          fileName: payload.fileName
        });
      });
    });
  } catch (error) {
    return Boom.badRequest(error.message);
  }
};
```